# What kind of timecode is this? (possibly ble specific)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, timecodes

I am working on making a custom controller for an aquarium light. I was able to figure out how to adjust the light's internal clock, and I was able to capture some of the communication, and I found this timecode `545f0d31574d52565951607631` which translated to ascii from hex becomes `` T_ 1WMRVYQ`v1 ``. I know for sure it's the timecode, because it works as expected.

Anyone know what it is? Is it BLE specific? anyone know how to alter it?

I'm pretty sure the first 4 numbers are not part of the code, but a indicator for the device.

Edit:

It is BLE. I should have been more clear. It does most of the transmission on UUID 1000, with the characteristic uuid being 1001. The device doesn't have a built-in clock that I can see. It turn's on and off at the times I specify in the developer’s app. After a power failure, it "resets" to midnight. I know that value is the timecode, because when I input it using gatter tools, I can see the light reacts accordingly. I added a photo of it updating. –

Answer (score 1):

You hint that that this is a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.

If it is BLE, then the UUID of the characteristic might be in the [16-bit UUID Numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) document. If it is a custom characteristic, then it will not. Official characteristics have the base address of `0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` and only the four missing values are documented.

The specification for how time can be shared over BLE is documented in the [GATT Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/) if it is a Bluetooth SIG adopted characteristic.

It might be helpful if you update the question with what this values gives as the value on the light's internal clock.

Comment: @GarratheWinnie, you need to add the additional information (e.g. photo) to the question not this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an edit to the op. I’m new to this site